# How to restrict KeyEvent capture speed

Tags: java, awt, keylistener, keyevent

I'm making a fairly basic top down 2D shooting game (think Space Invaders) but I'm having an issue with KeyEvent processing too many events per second.

I have this:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
    shoot();
}
```

shoot() creates a bullet and sets it firing upward, but a problem arises if you simply hold down space to fire hundreds of bullets, making the game trivial.

Is there a way to make it process only one or two keypresses per second, ignoring the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a handmade timer so that it will be either lightweight either easily customizable, something like:

```
long lastShoot = System.currentTimeMillis();
final long threshold = 500; // 500msec = half second

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { 
  if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
  {
     long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
     if (now - lastShoot > threshold)
     {
       shoot();
       lastShoot = now;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: He's talking about 2 shoots per second, I don't think that `nanoTime() `would make so much difference in this case.

Comment: I was thinking of something along those lines but for some reason I thought it would be a lot more complicated. And yes, I don't need ultra accuracy with the timing so milliseconds are fine. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

In that type of game, isn't it usual that there is only one bullet allowed on the screen a time? Don't allow shooting until the current bullet has hit something or disappeared off the top of the screen.

Comment: Traditionally yes, but there's a bit more going on in this game which requires a slightly higher rate of fire.